# Dojo Dialog dont want to block whole page

Tags: dojo

I'm  displaying a grid within the dialog with no issues. But the problem is, dialog is blocking the entire page on the background. Is there anyway to avoid it? i.e. once dialog is displayed, user can still access the page elements like Tab etc..

Comment: think there is a property call modal that will enable or disable the background

Answer (score 1):

It's possibile by using CSS. When you create a `Dialog` and give it the `id` property, it will create an underlying `<div>` that spans the entire page so you can't click anything except on that new underlying `<div>`. Luckily, you can hide such an element with CSS, and because the ID of the element is generated as `#<ID of dialog>_underlay`, you can simply do this like this:

```js
require(['dijit/Dialog', 'dijit/form/Button', 'dojo/domReady!'], function(Dialog, Button) {
  var dialog = new Dialog({
    id: 'test',
    title: 'Test',
    content: 'Hello world'
  });

  new Button({}, 'btn').on('click', function() {
    dialog.show();
  });
});
```

```css
/* "test" is the ID of the dialog, so I need to use #test_underlay */
#test_underlay {
  /* Setting this property to none hides the element */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: false"></script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
  <button id="btn">Click me</button>
  <input type="checkbox" />Can you still select me?
</body>
```

Comment: Using this solution causes some event conflict with some other widget like dgrids table .

Comment: @g00glen00b: Let me try this solution today and update you back. Thanks for taking time to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Dialog you can use FloatingPane of Dojo. It works approximately the same way and you can use the objects under it.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer!

Comment: I can comment only my answers. When I try the site tell me _'You must have 50 reputation to comment.'_

Comment: Yes, then gain reputation first!

Comment: I'm gaining..sorry

Comment: Hope this helps you!: [Six simple tips to get reputation fast on any Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-reputation-fast-on-any-stack-exchange-site)